# Forward SSH through SSH tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

My situation :

Me(localhost) -> Server A(ip:100.100.100.100) =>(server B(ip:192.168.25.100),server....)

i'm able to SSH into server since it has a true ip
if i then want to connect to server b, i would ssh server b with it's ip(192.168.25.100)

example:

from my pc:

```
ssh user@100.100.100.100
```

then in 100.100.100.100,

```
ssh user@192.168.25.100
```

this would get me to server B with ssh

what if i want to connect to server b directly?
how can i do that?

example:

from my oc:

```
ssh@192.168.25.100
```

i have tried the following:

```
ssh -L 22:localhost:22 user@100.100.100.100
```

without success

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your problem is in binding a listener to localhost:22; there's already an sshd listening on that.  Tunnelling an ssh connection through an ssh connection is completely lawful, and I do it all the time, but you need to pick unused ports for your forwarding listeners.

Try

```
me% ssh user@100.100.100.100 -L 2201:192.168.25.100:22
```

then

```
me% ssh localhost -p 2201
```

You should end up on server B (unless something's already bound to me:2201, in which case, pick another port).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! it does work, however, how i can forward all connections instead of only ssh(22)?

Comment: That's a full-blown VPN you're looking for, not just port-forwarding.  There's a writeup on how to do vpn-over-ssh at http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/VPN-Over-SSH , but it requires remote root access via ssh on A.  Or you could look into OpenVPN or other VPN solutions, but again, you'll need privilege on A to make these work.

Comment: thanks a lot, one last thing, what if i only want to connect to A?

Comment: `me% ssh user@100.100.100.100` ;  didn't we already cover that?  or do you mean "what if I want a full-blown VPN to A?", in which case my answer stands.

Comment: the vpn one, everything works like a charm! thanks!

Comment: For people who want VPN over SSH, don't have root access on the server but it does have Python, try [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle).

Comment: Love this answer! My localhost was able to login to "server B" root with an ssh key! Thumbs way the hell up!

Answer (score 35):

You don't have to use ssh port forwarding to ssh into an internal computer through a proxy. You can use the ssh feature of executing a command on the first server you connect to in order to ssh into a 3rd computer.

```
ssh -t user@100.100.100.100 ssh user@192.168.25.100
```

The `-t` option forces ssh to allocate a pseudo-tty so you can run an interactive command.

This can work with ssh keys as well. If you have your private and public key on machine A and your public key in the authorized keys files on machines B and C, then you can use the `-A` option to forward the authentication agent connection.

Comment: Use `-A` with caution and only if the jump host is fully trusted. A safer and simpler alternative is to use `ssh -J jumphost destination` if the `-J` option is available.

Answer (score 18):

As of OpenSSH 7.3 (late 2016) the easiest way is the [ProxyJump](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Passing_Through_One_or_More_Gateways_Using_ProxyJump) setting.  In your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host B
  ProxyJump A
```

Or on the command line, `-J B`.

Answer (score 11):

I used a different solution. I used a `ProxyCommand` option (here in `~/.ssh/config`):

```
Host myinsidehost1 myinsidehost2 myinsidehost3
ProxyCommand ssh externalhost ssh %h sshd -i
```

This doesn't set up any port-to-port tunnel, instead tunnels ssh by using standard stdin/out. This method has a drawback that there are actually three ssh connections to authenticate. But  to connect to the internal host you just type:

```
ssh myinsidehost2
```

...so you do not need to care about choosing any IP for that tunnel.

Comment: This is the only kind of SSH stacking that I find working. I've been tried `corkscrew` or `nc` (`netcat`) but none work as seamlessly as this.

Answer (score 8):

according to the ssh man page, ProxyCommand is the correct method

the syntax being:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p user@jumphost 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: I am not sure the `-W` option existed when this question was answered. But with newer versions of the ssh client, I agree that the combination of `ProxyCommand` and `-W` is the preferred method. Maybe add some context showing both how it can be used on the command line as well as an example of a section for `.ssh/config`.

Comment: Any idea where to find the changelogs/version info that tells us which versions of SSH have the `-W` command and which don't? A bit of googling did not yield answers quickly for me...

Comment: `-W` got introduced with OpenSSH 5.4, released in 2010. So the answer is yes @kasperd

Answer (score 5):

While `ProxyJump` has already been mentioned, it's most useful for static hosts you keep connecting to. If the machines keep changing, it's much easier to use `-J` (jump host) command line argument:

Once you know what it's doing, the syntax is pretty straightforward:

`ssh -J user1@100.100.100.100 user2@192.168.25.100`

The above command establishes a connection to 100.100.100.100 as user1, then from there "jumps" to 192.168.25.100 as user2